# How to obtain a Thai visa for a baby without a passport?

Tags: visas, thailand, children

A couple with a baby is travelling to Thailand as tourists (both parents have a three month tourist visa obtained from a Thai consulate outside of Thailand). What visa does the baby need and how is it obtained, especially if the baby does not have its own passport?

I have searched online for an answer to this question, but all the links I have found are about child visas for "non-immigrant" (not tourist) visas or family-child reunions.

Comment: How can the baby travel without a passport?

Comment: I have no idea, isn't that possible in some countries by a special stamp on both parent's passports?

Comment: Do you know any countries that do this? I know India did this before 1998 where minors were endorsed in parents passports. But I think this is a thing of the past, now most countries don't do this, and issue passports to minors.

Comment: Ireland used to do this and not just for babies.  When I was young, the whole family travelled on my father's passport.  There was a space for the wife's photo but just for names of children.  Probably the UK as well.  I did not see it used with a UK passport but it had a space for a wife's photo.  A child's passport needed to be updated sfter 5 years, they would add a new photo in the wife's space.

Comment: "Nonimmigrant" is a category that covers visas for temporary visitors and short-term residents such as students.  It includes tourist visas.  As @badjohn notes it used to be common for children to be able to travel on a parents passport, and you still occasionally see mention of this in immigration law or passport/visa regulations, but most countries require children to have their own passports to enter (and therefore visas) and many countries have abandoned the practice of listing children in parents' passports.

Comment: @phoog I just looked at my old passports.  A UK one issued in 1971 has space for a wife's photo and details and there is just a small space for children's details.  Note "wife", it is assumed that the main holder is the husband (and no provision for same sex marriages).  The wife's photo space actually contains an updated photo of me.  An Irish one issued in 1991 has similar space for wife and children.  Neither current one does.

Comment: A mistake there.  1991 was the expiry not the issue date of the Irish passport.  So, one issued in 1981 had provision for wife and children.  My next one, issue in 1990, did not.  So, this facility ended some time between 1981 and 1990.

Comment: @nikhil why ask rhetorical questions? They just confuse simple issues.

Comment: @Fattie Nikhil just said that it used to happen like that and its not anymore. Its a good information.

Comment: hi @AnishSheela !  What I meant is: phrasing things as a **rhetorical question** really adds confusion.  Just state in plain direct English, your thoughts.  For example "The baby needs a passport."  Rhetorical questions are a huge negative on sites like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot do international travel without a passport (with some exceptions like schengen area and us-canada border). This applies to a newborn baby also.

If the baby is born overseas, you can approach respective embassy to get passport. If birthright citizenship does apply (eg: USA), then the current country can also issue passport to the baby.

Visa is given for a passport. Without passport, you cannot get a visa.

Comment: I was born on a US military base in W Germany. I had a US passport issued and traveled home to the US on it at 3 month old. This was... a few moons ago, so it's not like this is a new requirement.

Answer (score -4):

US babies need a passport and visa. There was a time when babies could be on a parent’s passport - but no more.

If a baby born in another country qualifies for US citizenship, there is a stack of paperwork to be completed and submitted to the local US embassy. The baby will get a certificate as an American Born Abroad, which can be used to get a US passport

Comment: There’s no mention of a US aspect in the OP’s question